# Node.js chaining promises but still executing out of order

Tags: node.js

Hello so i'm trying to execute 3 things in order.

1. First then: generate images
2. Second then: zip them up
3. Third then: email them

Generating and zipping the images is working fine, but when I go to email them, the zip file hasn't been populated so it's just sending an empty zip. Any tips here?

```
rowData().then(res => {
        let functionArray;      
        if(client == 'TCS'){
            functionArray = TCSFunctionArray;
        } else{
            console.log('Please enter a valid client name');
        }
        
        let images = [];
        //generating all the images
        for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < functionArray.length; j++){
                images.push(nodeHtmlToImage({
                    output: `${PATH}/row_${i+2}_${functionArray[j].name}.png`,
                    html: functionArray[j](res[i]).html,
                    puppeteerArgs: {defaultViewport: {height: functionArray[j](res[i]).height, 
                                                        width: functionArray[j](res[i]).width, 
                                                        deviceScaleFactor: 2}, args: ["--no-sandbox"]}
                }))
            }
        }
        return Promise.all(images);
    }).then(() => {
       zipBanners(PATH, dest)
    }).then(() => {
        emailBanners(dest)
    })

function zipBanners(sourceFolder, dest){
    tar.c(
        {
          gzip: true
        },
        [sourceFolder]
      ).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));
}
```

Comment: Can you add the zipBanners function snippet to your question?

Comment: Yes just added.

Comment: Which tar package are you using?

Comment: node-tar ==> https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar

Answer (score 1):

If your zipBanners returns a promise, make sure you return it for your third `then` call:

```
return zipBanners(PATH, dest)
```

Otherwise, you're just saying to start running the zipBanners function and then immediately go to the emailing part of your promise chain even though zip file hasn't been populated yet.